# Show that the solution $(I,y)$ to an ODE $\dot{y} = X(t,y)$, with $X\in C^k(D_{X}, \mathbb{R}^n)$, is in $C^{k+1}(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $k=0,1,2,3,\dots$ and $X\in C^k(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ I want to show that any solution $(I,y)$ to $\dot{y}=X(t,y)$ satisfies that $y\in C^{k+1}(I,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

For $n=1$ it might not be so bad, since $X: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $y$ satisfies $\dot{y}(t) = X(t,y(t))$ for all $t\in I$, so on $I$ the derivative of $y$ is $X$, which is $k$ times continuous differentiable and $X$ itself is continuous, so it seems that $y$ is $k+1$ times continuously differentiable, but I fear that the higher dimension case becomes more complicated, since the derivatives become matrices...
I don't quite know how to start, I considered induction in $n$ (induction in $k$ does not seem like the right approach).

Maybe one also needs to consider e.g. that $y^{(2)}(t) = \dot{X}(t, y(t))\dot{y}(t)$, which could be where the induction assumption is used.

Comment: There is only one derivative in the time direction which is the relevant one. Where are the matrices coming from?

Comment: Ah there might not be matrices! I think I might be confused about what to show.

Comment: Use the same idea for one dimensional case in higher dimensions. You know $y$ is $C^k$ and so $X(t, y(t))$ is also $C^k$. This implies that $y$ is $C^{k+1}$.

Comment: Say for definiteness that $X$ is $C^{10}$. If you assume $y$ is differentiable and satisfies $\dot{y}(t)=X(t,y(t))$, then the RHS is continuous so $\dot{y}$ is continuous and hence $y$ is $C^1$. But now if $y$ is $C^1$ then $t\mapsto X(t,y(t))$ is $C^1$ (composition of $C^{10}$ with $C^1$ is definitely $C^1$). So, $\dot{y}$ is $C^1$, meaning $y$ is $C^2$. Now, continue again, you'll see $\dot{y}$ is $C^2$ hence $y$ is $C^3$. Keep going. As for why composition of functions inherits the minimum of the smoothness, you just use chain rule once and this type of inductive argument.

Comment: Thank you @peek-a-boo. That makes a lot of sense!